# Concat two lists of different object in couples using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of objects EnTeteCommande (which each have 3 properties) and a list of strings.
I want to concat the elements of these 2 lists couples.
For example :

```
List<EnteteCommande> Ent = new List<List<EnteteCommande>();
Ent.Add(E1); // E1 : { code = 011 , Date = 10/05/2016 , Ref = 01236 }
Ent.Add(E2); // E1 : { code = 012 , Date = 10105/2016 , Ref = 01237 }
List<string> Status = new List<List<string>>();
Status = { "test1" , "test2"}
```

The result that I want is:

```
r1 : { code = 011 , Date = 10/05/2016 , Ref = 01236 , statut = "test1"}
r2 : { code = 012 , Date = 10105/2016 , Ref = 01237 , statut = "test2" }
```

I used linq's Zip but I can't display the result in razor

```
 var historiques = Ent as List<AURES_GROS_EnTeteCommande>;
                    var statuts = statuts as List<string>;
                    var resultats = historiques.Zip(statuts, (item, statut) => new { item = item, statut = statut });
                    ViewBag.resultats = resultats;
```

and this my code in razor view :

```
foreach (var it in ViewBag.resultats)
                            {
                                <tbody>
                                <tr class="even pointer">
                                    <td class="a-center ">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="tableflat" value="" name="ids" id="ids">
                                    </td>
                                    <td> @it.item.Code</td>
                                    <td> @it.item.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                                    <td> @it.item.Ref</a></td>
                                    <td>
                                        @it.statut
                                    </td>
</tbody>
```

Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: use the `.zip` in `linq`

Comment: I used but it did'nt work

Answer (score 3):

```
ent.Zip(status, (e,s) =>new {e.code, e.Date, e.Ref, status = s})
```

Working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eay1Zw

```
    List<EnteteCommande> Ent = new List<EnteteCommande>();
    var E1 = new EnteteCommande { code = "011" , Date = "10/05/2016" , Ref = "01236" };
    var E2 = new EnteteCommande { code = "012" , Date = "10105/2016" , Ref = "01237" };
    Ent.Add(E1); 
    Ent.Add(E2); 
    List<string> Status = new List<string>{ "test1" , "test2"};

    var result = Ent.Zip(Status, (e,s) => new {e.code, e.Date, e.Ref, status = s}).ToList();
```

Comment: T tried your code AD.Net , it return all rows with the same statut

Comment: thanks AD.Net for your help , but I did'nt understand why your code display the same statut for alla rows ol list Ent

Comment: this is the output `011, 10/05/2016, 01236, test1
012, 10105/2016, 01237, test2`

Comment: how can I display result in razor view